# Difference between AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM and AutoModelForCausalLM

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

As per the title, how are these two Auto Classes on Huggingface different from each other? I tried reading the documentation but did not find differentiating information

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Intuitively, `AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM` is used for language models with **encoder-decoder architecture**, like T5 and BART, while `AutoModelForCausalLM` is used for **auto-regressive** language models like all the GPT models.

These two classes are conceptual APIs to automatically infer a specific model class for the two types of models, e.g., `GPT2LMHeadModel` using `AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained('gpt2')`. For example, You can see the [source code](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v3.5.1/_modules/transformers/modeling_auto.html) for all the inference models. (`MODEL_FOR_CAUSAL_LM_MAPPING`  and `MODEL_FOR_SEQUENCE_CLASSIFICATION_MAPPING`)