# Implementation (and working) differences between AutoModelForCausalLMWithValueHead vs AutoModelForCausalLM?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, large-language-model

> Before any of you mark it as a "Community Specific" or something else, just [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75549632/difference-between-automodelforseq2seqlm-and-automodelforcausallm) which you people so proudly have marked as **Part of NLP Collective**.

I know what is `AutoModelForCausalLM`. The thing I'm asking is that in the [`peft` LoRA Fine tuning tutorial](https://huggingface.co/docs/trl/v0.7.1/lora_tuning_peft), the autors have used `AutoModelForCausalLMWithValueHead` while you pick any code or notebook on Fine-tuning of any LLM with `PEFT` style, you'll find `AutoModelForCausalLM` being used.

I went to lean on the [official documentation of `AutoModelForCausalLMWithValueHead`](https://huggingface.co/docs/trl/models) and found:

> An autoregressive model with a value head in addition to the language model head

What I want to ask is that **How, where and more importantly, *WHY* this extra `ValueHead` is used**

In case you don't know the answer, you try to upvote the question rather than trying to close it, please. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

First things first, this additional ValueHead has nothing to do with PEFT.

Mainly, PPO optimization (a RLHF technique) relies on computing "advantages" associated with taking a particular action (in this case, selecting a token) in a particular state. The computation relies on value of (state,action) pair minus, the value of being in the state. You can review the exact calculation in this function: https://github.com/huggingface/trl/blob/main/trl/trainer/ppo_trainer.py#L1148

The additional ValueHead simply projects the last hidden states onto a scalar to estimate the value of a state. Check the ValueHead class implementation here: https://github.com/huggingface/trl/blob/main/trl/models/modeling_value_head.py#L21

Note: The ValueHead class is only needed if you plan to perform training/re-training.